# Show that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,$\exists! k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ s.t. $\frac{k}{2}(k-1)<n\leq\frac{k}{2}(k+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

The question states as follows:

Show that for any positive integer $n$, there is exactly one positive integer $k$ for which $\frac{k}{2}(k-1)<n\leq\frac{k}{2}(k+1)$. Give a formula for finding this $k$ using floor functions.

Now, I proved the initial statement as follows:

$\frac{k}{2}(k+1)=\sum_{i=1}^ki$ where $i\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\frac{k}{2}(k-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i$ where $i\in \mathbb{Z}$

Therefore, we have two inequalities:

$-n+1+2+3+...+k\geq 0$ and $-n+1+2+3+...+(k-1)< 0$

From this, we can see that for any positive integer, $n$, there exists a unique $k$ such that the above inequalities hold true. Pick any $n$, then, as we compute the sum $-n+1+2+3+...+k$, we will reach a $k$ such that $-n+1+2+3+...+k\geq 0$, and therefore  trivially $-n+1+2+3+...+(k-1)< 0$. This is the unique $k$ for the chosen $n$.

This, however, is where I get stuck. I'm not seeing how I can generate a formula for "finding this $k$ using floor functions."

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Take $k$ the integer which "best approximate" $\sqrt{2n}$. That is:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
k = [\sqrt{2n}] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ if } \{\sqrt{2n} \} \in [0,\frac{1}{2})\\ 
k = [\sqrt{2n}]+1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ if } \{\sqrt{2n} \} \in (\frac{1}{2},1)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Here I denoted by $[x]$ the integer part of $x$ and by $\{x \}$ the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: I see that this works, however, I'm not sure I see where $\sqrt{2n}$ is coming from.

Comment: $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}<n\le \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is equivalent to $k(k-1)<2n\le k(k+1)$. So intuitively, $k$ should be "approximately" $\sqrt{2n}$.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: Have you succeed in proving that the value of $k$ from my hint really works?

Comment: This is only the intuitive part of the solution. But you need to $\textbf{prove}$ that the double inequality in your problem holds true for that specific value $k$.